# how to hide fragment(in FrameLayout) and show viewpager fragment?

Tags: android, android-viewpager, fragment, android-framelayout

I am having activity which contains ViewPager,TabLayout and NavigationDrawer. The navigation drawer contains items(say 10). I also got FrameLayout to load fragments when navigation drawer items clicked.

Here in viewpager i got 3 fragments(Say BreakFast,Lunch,Dinner). In navigation drawer list items i also got same items as in the viewpager.

Now when i click first three items the viewpager fragments works fine.After clicking fourth item in drawer(i.e Check Calories) the check calories fragment of Framelayout loaded successfully.Now when i click back the BreakFast,Lunch or Dinner item,the viewpager fragment is not loading by replacing FrameLayout fragment. Do come up with some solution.

Here is my Code

public class HomeScreen extends AppCompatActivity {

```
TabLayout tabLayout;
ViewPager viewPager;
RelativeLayout menuNavigation, menuImageLayout;
DrawerLayout mDrawerLayout;
NavigationListItemAdapter navigationListItemAdapter;
ListView mDrawerList;
ImageView homepageMenu, locationImage;
de.hdodenhof.circleimageview.CircleImageView profileImage;
Button checkout;
TextView title;
FloatingActionButton filterActionButton;
FrameLayout fragmentContainer;
Fragment fragment = null;
boolean doubleBackToExitPressedOnce = false;

int imageArray[] = {R.raw.break_fast_white, R.raw.lunch_white, R.raw.dinner_white, R.raw.calories_white, R.raw.profile_white,
        R.raw.about_us_white, R.raw.contact_us_white, R.raw.help_white, R.raw.policy_info_white, R.raw.logout_color};
String titleArray[] = {"Break Fast", "Lunch", "Dinner", "Check Calories", "My Profile", "About Us", "Contact Us", "Help", "Privacy Info", "Logout"};

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activty_home_screen);
    StatusBarTheme.setStatusBarColor(this);
    initiateView();
    fontStyle();

    try {

        LunchBoxUtil.setImageDrawable(this, R.raw.menu, homepageMenu);
        LunchBoxUtil.setImageDrawable(this, R.raw.filter, filterActionButton);
        LunchBoxUtil.setImageDrawable(this, R.raw.location, locationImage);
        LunchBoxUtil.setImageDrawable(this, R.raw.photo_circle, profileImage);
        title.setText(R.string.app_name);

        setupViewPager(viewPager);
        tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(viewPager);
        navigationListItemAdapter = new NavigationListItemAdapter(getApplicationContext(), titleArray, imageArray);
        mDrawerList.setAdapter(navigationListItemAdapter);

        menuImageLayout.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                boolean drawerOpen = mDrawerLayout.isDrawerOpen(menuNavigation);
                if (!drawerOpen) {
                    mDrawerLayout.openDrawer(menuNavigation);
                } else {
                    mDrawerLayout.closeDrawer(menuNavigation);
                }
            }
        });

        filterActionButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(HomeScreen.this, FilterByCategory.class);
                startActivity(intent);
                //overridePendingTransition(R.anim.expand_in, R.anim.demo_slide_out);
            }
        });

        mDrawerList.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                displayFragments(position);
            }
        });

        checkout.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(HomeScreen.this, DemoScreenMain.class);
                startActivity(intent);
                overridePendingTransition(R.anim.demo_slide_in, R.anim.demo_slide_out);
            }
        });

        if (savedInstanceState == null) {
            fragmentContainer = new FrameLayout(this);
        }

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

@Override
public void onBackPressed() {

    if (mDrawerLayout.isDrawerOpen(menuNavigation)) {
        mDrawerLayout.closeDrawer(menuNavigation);
    } else {

        if (doubleBackToExitPressedOnce) {
            super.onBackPressed();
            return;
        }

        this.doubleBackToExitPressedOnce = true;
        Toast.makeText(this, "Press BACK again to exit", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                doubleBackToExitPressedOnce = false;

            }
        }, 2000);
    }
}

private void displayFragments(int position) {
    switch (position) {

        case 0:
            mDrawerLayout.closeDrawer(menuNavigation);
            fragmentContainer.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            viewPager.setCurrentItem(0);
            break;

        case 1:
            mDrawerLayout.closeDrawer(menuNavigation);
            fragmentContainer.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            viewPager.setCurrentItem(1);
            break;

        case 2:
            mDrawerLayout.closeDrawer(menuNavigation);
            fragmentContainer.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            viewPager.setCurrentItem(2);
            break;

        case 3:
            mDrawerLayout.closeDrawer(menuNavigation);
            fragment = new CalculateCalories();
            title.setText(R.string.calories);
            filterActionButton.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            break;

        case 4:
            mDrawerLayout.closeDrawer(menuNavigation);
            Intent intent = new Intent(this, UserProfile.class);
            startActivity(intent);
            break;

        case 5:
            mDrawerLayout.closeDrawer(menuNavigation);
            fragment = new AddressDetails();
            title.setText(R.string.address_details);
            filterActionButton.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            break;

        case 6:
            mDrawerLayout.closeDrawer(menuNavigation);
            fragment = new ContactUs();
            title.setText(R.string.contactus);
            filterActionButton.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            break;
    }

    if (fragment != null) {
        FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
        FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
        fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.frame_container_fragment, fragment);
        fragmentTransaction.commit();
    }
}

private void initiateView() {
    mDrawerLayout = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    menuNavigation = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.relative_navigtion);
    menuImageLayout = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.menu_image_rl);
    homepageMenu = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.home_menu_Img);
    locationImage = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.user_location_Img);
    profileImage = (de.hdodenhof.circleimageview.CircleImageView) findViewById(R.id.profile_picture);
    filterActionButton = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);
    fragmentContainer = (FrameLayout) findViewById(R.id.frame_container_fragment);
    mDrawerList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.drawer_menu_items_List);
    title = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.home_title_Txt);
    viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.viewpager);
    tabLayout = (TabLayout) findViewById(R.id.tabs);
    checkout = (Button) findViewById(R.id.checkout_Btn);
}

private void fontStyle() {

    Typeface robotoRegular = FontUtility.getRobotoRegular(this);
    Typeface robotoMedium = FontUtility.getRobotoMedium(this);

    title.setTypeface(robotoMedium);
    checkout.setTypeface(robotoRegular);
}

private void setupViewPager(ViewPager viewPager) {
    ViewPagerAdapter adapter = new ViewPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
    adapter.addFragment(new BreakFastFragment(), "BreakFast");
    adapter.addFragment(new LunchFragment(), "Lunch");
    adapter.addFragment(new DinnerFragment(), "Dinner");
    viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);
}

class ViewPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {
    private final List<Fragment> mFragmentList = new ArrayList<>();
    private final List<String> mFragmentTitleList = new ArrayList<>();

    public ViewPagerAdapter(FragmentManager manager) {
        super(manager);
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        return mFragmentList.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return mFragmentList.size();
    }

    public void addFragment(Fragment fragment, String title) {
        mFragmentList.add(fragment);
        mFragmentTitleList.add(title);
    }

    @Override
    public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
        return mFragmentTitleList.get(position);
    }
}
```

}

Here is my xml layout code

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    android:id="@+id/coordinatorLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/main_lay"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <include
            android:id="@+id/action_bar"
            layout="@layout/tool_bar_layout" />

        <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
            android:id="@+id/tabs"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/action_bar"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
            android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
            app:tabTextAppearance="@style/MyCustomTextAppearance" />

        <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
            android:id="@+id/viewpager"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_above="@+id/checkout_Btn"
            android:layout_below="@+id/tabs" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/checkout_Btn"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:background="@color/standard_brown"
            android:text="Checkout"
            android:textColor="@color/colorAccent"
            android:textSize="@dimen/text_size_18sp" />

    </RelativeLayout>

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/frame_container_fragment"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginTop="?actionBarSize" />

    <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/fab"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom|right"
        android:layout_marginBottom="100dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:visibility="visible"
        app:backgroundTint="@color/standard_brown"
        app:fabSize="normal" />

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>

<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/relative_navigtion"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="start"
    android:clickable="false">

    <include
        android:id="@+id/navgation_drawer"
        layout="@layout/navigation_drawer_layout" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: You are not resetting the reference to your fragment in displayFragment function due to which in case of viewPager items it contains reference of last loaded fragment and the code for fragment transaction always runs. That could be part of the problem.

Comment: Could you able to explain this even more specific??